# Netbeans mySQL Connection error

Tags: mysql

Hi everybody I'm new and I'm having some trouble with a connection with netbeans and mysql, I need a database online I created one at 000webhost.com but I think that something's wrong .... if any have some idea or other server I really need to connect a database from a server online with an app in netbeans... Please I'm new in this all ideas you have come on..

here it's a pic
[image]

Answer (score 2):

mySQL servers usually provide connection only for localhost or a local subnet for security reasons.
Are you sure the server you are trying to connect is reachable from your IP address ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I entered to teh database on the web by phpmyadmin and it shows me the db and the tables all is correct the information of the name, the user pass of the db and the host are correct I think this free hosting provider doesn't not allow remote connections like mysql on port 3306 , in that case do you know any hosting provider that allow that kind of service???

Comment: I don't know any, as I said it is a very common (and good) practice to block this port from the internet.